# InterlockedCompareExchange64 vs std::atomic compare_exchange

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

How is `std::atomic<>` [compare_exchange](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange)() related and translated to/from MS [InterlockedCompareExchange64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683562(v=vs.85).aspx) on a non-atomic value? Are there performance or semantics differences?

For example, are these codes equivalent?

***edit*** : David Haim pointed out that it should have been `int64_t atomic_inc_ms(volatile int64_t& val, int64_t less_than)`

```
int64_t atomic_inc_ms(int64_t& val, int64_t less_than) {
 int64_t new_val;
 int64_t old_val = val; 
 while(true)
 {
   if (old_val > less_than) return old_val;
   new_val = old_val + 1;
   int64_t got_val = InterlockedCompareExchange64(&val,new_val,old_val);
   if(got_val == old_val) break;
   old_val = got;
 }

 return new_val;
}
```

and

```
int64_t atomic_inc(std::atomic<int64_t>& val, int64_t less_than) {
 int64_t new_val;
 int64_t old_val = val.load();
 do
 {
   if (old_val > less_than) return old_val;
   new_val = old_val + 1;
 } while (!val.compare_exchange_weak(old_val, new_val));

 return new_val;
}
```

A concern is the line `int64_t old_val = val;` with no explicit atomic load.

The example is that of [Is there atomic increment with the check preconditions, that the atomic value was less than the specified value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778110/is-there-atomic-increment-with-the-check-preconditions-that-the-atomic-value-wa) and is close to the text book example on how to use `compare_exchange_weak`.

Are `compare_exchange_weak` and `compare_exchange`, semantically equivalent to
`InterlockedCompareExchangeAcquire64` and `InterlockedCompareExchange64` ?

Comment: both will compile to the same thing, aka `lock inc [ptr]`, so no worries. but your code shows why the standard is better, your `val` is not volatile, while `Interlocked*` requires volatile variable. you don't need to think about it when you use `atomic`. plus the protability

Comment: @DavidHaim. Thank you! I agree 100%. You beat me to realize this, while I was commenting SergeyA's answer. I had an unclear consern about what the compiler can do with val.

Comment: @DavidHaim, do I understand you right (the edit I made, now `volatile int64_t& val`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those codes are semantically equivalent. No atomic load for `int64_t` is of no concern here, since `Interlocked*` family functions hint X86, where all loads are atomic.

There is a chance that c++ atomics will behave slightly faster than `Interlocked*` functions, since compiler will generate direct ASM call rather than call a function. However, compiler might recognize `Interlocked*` function as well.

Comment: Ok. Great! And, my code 'int64_t old_val = val;'. There´s no need for volatile or other marker that val can be changed from other thread? Perhaps `volatile int64_t& val`?

Answer (score 0):

std::atomic is C++ standard. It is portable code that will compile with any compliant compiler

Interlocked* are Windows-specific functions from Windows SDK. Hence that code will not be portable.

Comment: Thank you. That's true but not answering any of the questions I had regarding the semantics.

Comment: AFAIK these differences would probably be too low to measure